# Find matches or no matches between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql so let me apologize before I start.

I am trying to flag matches on what I would call a policy number in the following way.

```
Select c.last_name, c.first_name, c.sex, c.date_of_birth, c.record_nbr, 
case when ph.policy_nbr = cp.policy_nbr then ph.policy_nbr else 'No Match'

From table ph

Left join client c
On ph.last_name = c.last_name
And ph.first_name = c.first_name
And ph.date_of_birth = c.date_of_birth
And ph.sex = c.sex
Left join person_payer cp
On c.person_id = cp.person_id

Group by c.last_name, c.first_name,c.date_of_birth, 
c.sex,ph.policy_num, cp.policy_nbr
```

The idea is to find a match beween the tables based on last name, first name, dob, and sex. Then I want to verify a match on policy number or a no match. Does the policy number exist in the patients record? Unfortunately this produces matches and no matches due to the existence of multiple policy numbers in the customers record. How can I make the report list the customer once and only once listing 'no match' or match on policy number.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you missing a join, since there's no join to table alias pp. And ph is alias to table named "table" right?

Comment: So I want to show customers where exact matches are found on lastname, firstname, dob and sex. Then report whether a matching policy number is found on the person_payer table for the client. The problem is that the person_payer table hold multiple policy numbers. I need it to show once and only once match found or no match found. I will add further, driving home now.

Comment: Sorry ramazan that should be cp

Comment: Ok, changed my answer after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming policy table's name is PolicyTable (as it's named table but sql server complains about it) you can do selection in single column instead of join.

```
Select c.last_name, c.first_name, c.sex, c.date_of_birth, c.record_nbr, 
ISNULL((Select top 1 ph.policy_nbr from PolicyTable ph where ph.last_name = c.last_name
And ph.first_name = c.first_name
And ph.date_of_birth = c.date_of_birth
And ph.sex = c.sex
And cp.policy_nbr = ph.policy_nbr), 'No Match') as PolicyNumber

From client c
Left join person_payer cp On c.person_id = cp.person_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces results but the query never stop running.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.last_name, c.first_name, c.sex, c.date_of_birth, c.record_nbr, 
isnull(cp.policy_nbr, 'No Match')

From table ph

Left join client c
On ph.last_name = c.last_name
And ph.first_name = c.first_name
And ph.date_of_birth = c.date_of_birth
And ph.sex = c.sex
Left join person_payer cp
On c.person_id = cp.person_id
and ph.policy_nbr = cp.policy_nbr 

Group by c.last_name, c.first_name,c.date_of_birth, 
c.sex,ph.policy_num, cp.policy_nbr
```

Comment: Thank you, however I have noticed that this generates results but there are a lot of null values in all columns.